# Create Alias in Azure Cognitive Search using C#

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

Just read the documentation about [creation of index alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-how-to-alias?tabs=sdk) using .Net SDK but had no success implementing it.

We are trying to simply run:
`// Create a SearchIndexClient
SearchIndexClient adminClient = new SearchIndexClient(serviceEndpoint, credential);

// Create an index alias
SearchAlias myAlias = new SearchAlias("my-alias", "hotel-quickstart-index");
adminClient.CreateAlias(myAlias);`

We are using SDK [V11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-dotnet-sdk-migration-version-11).

After adding the nugget package Azure.Search.Documents and the Azure.Core Visual Studio 2022 still can't recognize:

- SearchIndexClient

Using the last nuget package Azure.Search.Documents (11.4.0) the code sample should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index alias feature is in public preview. It's in the preview Azure SDK, per this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.indexes.models.searchalias?view=azure-dotnet-preview

It looks like it's in this package: Azure.Search.Documents v11.5.0-beta.4

Can you retry your code with that package?